# Single makefile that compiles kernel driver and .c file

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, operating-system

I have a **hello.c** file that prints Hello World, and I also have another **hello_driver.c** file that prints Hello World to the **kernel** **log**.

I can compile hello_driver.c file and it prints out Hello World to the kernel log **but** I can't compile those 2 .c files in same Makefile program.

I've tried this Makefile but it is not working:

```
obj-o += hello.o hello_driver.o

KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
     make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
     make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Please explain what is exactly not working. Build error? Runtime error?

Comment: If *hello.c* is a user space program, you need to have different *Makefile*, or at least use some ifdefery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 `makefiles` - one for hello.c and the other for hello_driver.c

Create a third makefile - this master makefile will call the above 2.

```
$(MAKE) -f <path/to/makefile1>
$(MAKE) -f <path/to/makefile2>
```